# Creating a data frame with pooled imputated values

Tags: r, dataframe, r-mice

So I want to do a regression analysis. and in order to account for missing data in my data set, I imputed NAs with mice. So far everything's fine, I ran mice() with m=5 and now I have the 5 imputation models. The next step according to the documentation would be to do the actual regression and combine the different imputation by using pool(), so:

```
model <- with (data_imp, exp  = ...)
summary(pool(model))
```

This will create the regression output for my analysis. Seems good so far.

However, I also want to provide some descriptive statistics (namely, a boxplot) on my dependent and independent variables. So therefore I need a dataframa that contains both a) the values that were already given and b) the combined, imputed values that were inserted in place of the NAs and used in the regression model. How can I create this data.frame?

I saw in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpnxwNXGV-E) tutorial know that you can combine the imputed data with the already given values into a new dataframe by using `data_full <- complete(data_imp)` but apparently thisonly works, if you want to specifically choose only one of the 5 imputations (for example `data_full <- complete(data_imp, 1)` to choose the first imputation). If you dont specifiy any nummer, I think it will just use the first imputation. I however want to use the combined, estimateed values from every 5 imputations and combine them into a dataframe. How can I do this?

I'd be really grateful for every piece of advice :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on how you want to display the data, but if you want to look at a box plot for each imputation, you can iterate through each of the 5 imputations run with `complete()` using `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` as per below:

```
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)

imp <- mice(nhanes)

map_dfr(1:5, ~ complete(imp, .x), .id = "imp") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = imp, y = bmi)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but thats not exactly what I meant. I want to visualize just one box plot with the pooled values that were ultimately used in the regression model

Comment: It doesn't do that though. From `?pool`, a model is fit in each imputed data set, and then the estimates from each of those models are pooled into a single set of estimates. There isn't one data set that the model is drawing from, but 5 (or whatever `m` is).

Comment: Yes I know that. And as you said, at the end there is this one single set of estimates. That is what I want: Combine this single set of estimates (cause these are the values that were ultimately used in the regression model, right? ) together with the values that were already given to create a full data frame without any NAs and visualize that

Comment: You're talking about the imputations of the observations with missingness. I'm talking about the estimates of the model parameters. At no point is there just one data frame with the missing values imputed.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the imputations. So does that mean that it is not possible to get these values?

Comment: I encourage you to read the documentation in `?pool`. It is clearly stated: "A common error is to [...] pool the multiply-imputed data instead of the estimates. Doing so may severely bias the estimates of scientific interest and yield incorrect statistical intervals and p-values."

Comment: "So does that mean that it is not possible to get these values?" It is possible - you could just take each of the imputed data sets and average their observation - but it is not advised to do that because you are not capturing the uncertainty that comes from the imputation - you are essentially treating the imputed values to be as "real" as the observed values.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks. So basically, the method doesn't pool the imputed data and then calculates the regression model but instead calculates `m` regression models and pools the coefficients? Did I get it right now? Then I understand what the problem is: "the combined, imputed values that were inserted in place of the NAs" I was talking about can't be put into the new data frame cause they are never actually calculated, right? And calculating the mean of the imputed values from the `m`data sets would create different, biased results

Comment: "So basically, the method doesn't pool the imputed data and then calculates the regression model but instead calculates m regression models and pools the coefficients? Did I get it right now?" Yes. There is no one final set of imputed data set, but rather `m` sets, and the pooled estimates from the model you run using those would accurately capture the uncertainty derived from the imputation process.

Comment: What you could do is this: `imp_data <- complete(imp_data, action = "long")`, then create a new column `imp_data$imp <- TRUE` and `data$imp <- FALSE`. Now you combine them with `bind_rows()`. Finally, you can plot the original values against all imputed values and use the `imp` column to distinguish them.